# NodeJS - Sequelize - Stored Procedure - is not working

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying do find what is the problem with my code below, I am using the plugin Tedious (SQL Server), sequelize and NodeJs:

```
exports.getCreditsGeneral = function(sgecode) {
    return sequelize.query('[dbo].[SP_ListaCreditos](:sgecode1)',
          { replacements:{sgecode1: sgecode}})
          .then(total => {        
               return total.length ? total : 0
          })
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing exec parameter

```
exports.getCreditsGeneral = function(sgecode) {
    return sequelize.query('exec [dbo].[SP_ListaCreditos](:sgecode1)',
          { replacements:{sgecode1: sgecode}})
          .then(total => {        
               return total.length ? total : 0
          })
}
```